# WL.JSONStore.init(data_collection) is not working in IBM Worklight 6.0.0 hybrid application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We tried to develop a simple angular hybrid app using IBM Worklight and we wanted to use JSONStore in our app. As per the Worklight documentation, we added JSONStore under other resources in `application-descriptor.xml` file  and in the code we created simple collection as follows.

```
var data_collection = {         
    people : {          
        searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}  
    }
};

var promise = WL.JSONStore.init(data_collection).then(function(){
    alert("init json store successfully!");     
    return true;        
}).fail(function (errorObject) {            
    alert("init json store failed!" + errorObject);             
    return false;       
});

return promise; 

};
```

But this code is not working for us. It is failing at `WL.JSONStore.init` method itself. Please help us in this regard.

Comment: Provide logs to see what is the exception.

Comment: In addition to the logs provide the other a complete snippet of your code.  There is an extra `}` in the snippet you provided. It looks like it was part of a function. Also, what error do you get in the `alert("init json store failed!" + errorObject); `

Comment: Do you have any updates on this issue? If you were able to solve your problem, post your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Yoel mentioned in the comments, the only evidence for an error appears to be from the extra } at the end.

Taking your code as-is and testing it in Worklight 6.2.0.01 (since you mentioned "worklight") in an Android environment produced a successful JSONStore init.

You'll need to edit your question with: the error message, where was this tested (environment, device/emulator/simulator), the worklight version, etc... if you want to pursue this any further.